# org.json.JSONObject constructor not accepting what appears to be a valid JSON string

Tags: java, android, json, android-json

I have a `string` in an `Android` app that I am trying to convert into a `JSONObject`. The `string` looks like this (except longer and with actual values instead of the dummy values I entered here):

```
[[{"1":"a"}],[{"1a":"1a","1b":"1b"},{"2a":"2a","2b":"2b"}]]
```

I have entered this exact `string` into two online `JSON validator`s, and both of them confirm it to be valid `JSON data`. So I would assume that the `JSONObject` constructor would be able to accept this string and convert it into a `JSONObject`. But when I try:

```
json = new JSONObject(result);
```

Where "result" is a String variable containing the string listed above, I get the following exception:

```
JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of [[{"1":"a"}],[{"1a":"1a","1b":"1b"},{"2a":"2a","2b":"2b"}]]
```

What's going on here? Is the `JSONObject`'s parser broken?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to create a JSONObject, but what you are actually giving it is a JSONArray.  Did you try creating a JSONArray instead?

Alternatively, you could wrap your array in an object so that you can create a JSONObject out of it.

Comment: Well, well. That was exactly the problem. Why didn't I see that? Thank you very much.

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json.toString())...This line throws an error saying "no suitable constructor found for JSONObject(String)"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [GSon library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) instead as it appears to be more full-featured.

In addition, it may be helpful to use [this tool](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to test your data (your data is valid btw):